# How to keep value of selected option after form is submitted in Laravel form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to make when user search by country on the page refresh eg. result page to keep selected country on the option on the form.

This is what I have where I populate the dropdown

```
@foreach ($countries as $country)
        <option value="{!! $country->id !!}">{!! $country->name !!}</option>
@endforeach
```

And this is what I have tried but seems that is not correct since the value isn't selected

```
@foreach ($countries as $country)
    <option value="{!! $country->id !!}"  @if( old('country->id')  == $country->id) selected="selected" @endif>{!! $country->name !!}</option>
@endforeach
```

What's the trick here?

Here is the controller

```
public function search(Request $request)
{

    $searchText = strip_tags($request['q']);
    $seachLocation = strip_tags($request['l']);


    $columns =['alias','description','address1','address2','address3'];

    $query = Item::select('*');

    $query->where( 'title', 'like', '%'.$searchText.'%');

    foreach( $columns as $column) {
        $query->orWhere( $column, 'like', '%'.$searchText.'%', '%'.$seachLocation.'%');
    }

    $query->orWhereHas('category',function( $query ) use (  $searchText ) {
        $query->where('title', 'like', '%'.$searchText.'%' );
    });

    $query->orWhereHas('country',function( $query ) use (  $searchText ) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$searchText.'%' );
    });

    $items = $query->paginate(5);
    $searchQuery = $searchText;
    $searchQueryLoc = $seachLocation;

    return view('search', compact('items','searchQuery','seachLocation'));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding <?php session()->getOldInput(); ?> and checking if the value country->id is available?

Comment: No, where I should add this?

Comment: Somewhere in your view. add <?php var_dump(session()->getOldInput()); ?> and submit the page and the post the results.

Comment: it is showing `array(0) { }` and btw with above code which I'm trying (my second sniped) it's always showing country with max ID in database selected by default.

Comment: Is array(0) {} after submitting the form? If so, are you redirecting to the view with old input? Please add in the part of your controller where you redirect

Comment: @pseudoanime, I've added function from the controller to the question.

Comment: can you add ->withInput(); to the end of the return statement and check if the  var_dump is populated?

Comment: I've tried it already (sorry that I didn't mentioned it). When I add `->withInput();` I've got error `Undefined offset: 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you use session to store the selected country. For example:

```
session()->put('forms.country', $request->get('country'));
```

Then your html should become:

```
<option value="{{ $country->id }}"  @if( session('forms.country')  == $country->id) selected="selected" @endif>{{ $country->name }}</option>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added session()-put... to my controller right before return view but still when is loading the page with the results the option dropdown is got default value

Comment: Are you doing search in the same method?

Comment: Yes, and it is in my question whole function for search

Comment: I would suggest that you put the portion where you search & just show in separate section. For example:

    if ($request->has('mode')) {
        // You search code goes here.
    }

Comment: Okay my mistake. It should be `session()->put('forms.country', $request->get('i'));` not `..$request->ge('country')...` Now is working

Comment: Hm, but this isn't good option I think because after search whatever other page on site I open it's always showing the last country searched. I mean after I leave the result page it's should reset to default one

Comment: You can always clear the session if you go to another page then back to the Search page.

Comment: The problem is that the form is visible on every page. I must somehow clear the session when the page is left

Comment: You can always use a middleware for this. In middleware you need to check if the current page url doesn't matches search page url. If it doesn't matches, then you should clear the session

Answer (score 6):

To use the `old()` helper, your form inputs need to have a name.

You then use the name of the input as the parameter in the `old()` helper to get the old value.

So using it like `old('country->id')` won't work; you need to use `old('nameAttributeOfInput')`.

A full example assuming the `name` attribute of this input is `country_id`:

```
@foreach ($countries as $country)
    <option value="{!! $country->id !!}"  @if( old('country_id')  == $country->id) selected="selected" @endif>{!! $country->name !!}</option>
@endforeach
```

As a side note, just be aware that `{!! !!}` does not escape the value being placed on the page which can be potentially dangerous. You would probably be just as fine, and safer, to use `{{ }}` which escapes the value.

Comment: Thanks but still doesn't show selected country. My select name has `name="l"` so my whole code is: `<option value="{!! $country->id !!}"  @if( old('l')  == $country->id) selected="selected" @endif>{!! $country->name !!}</option>`

Comment: What method does your form use? Can you show us more of your form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel inbuilt old() in form's field to hold the provided value.

```
 @if( old('field_name') == $country->id) selected="selected" @endif
```

Comment: @James answer is exactly same and I've wrote that doesn't work.